# JSF 2.2 - No "link" tag found

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, hyperlink, taglib

I would like to add a link in a JSF page. This is my code

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hey!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <f:view>

    <h:link value="Hey" outcome="dateMe" />
  </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, I get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 11, column: 4) No tag "link" defined in tag library imported with prefix "h"
```

I've read that this tag was introduced with JSF 2.0, but I checked and I'm using JSF 2.2.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you taglib imports. I editted my answer. Are you attached to `<h:link>`? @BackSlash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h:commandLink value="Hey" action="#{bean.action}" onclick="function()" />
```

You'll get the same functionality with different attributes. You could also consider:

```
<h:outputLink value="page.xhtml">
    <h:outputText value="Hey" />
</h:outputLink>
```

**EDIT**

Make sure your faces-config.xml is this. `<h:link>` is a newer component of JSF 2.0. Also make sure that you don't have JSF 1.x libraries in your `/WEB-INF/lib`, you need JSF 2.0 libraries.

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
```

Comment: Well... It's not the same thing... I want to redirect to a servlet, not to a bean action/xhtml page..

Comment: Your action from the bean could go through the servlet. However, that action can be other things to. I just use beans as my layer before I hit a servlet. @BackSlash

Comment: But why `h:link` doesn't work? I'm trying to understand this, it should be supported since JSF 2.0..